# grunt watch tasks no response after running

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a problem when I run "grunt" in my terminal, after I do some changes in my 
".scss" file nothing happens, the terminal still waitting.....
here is my gruntfile.js file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    var config = grunt.file.readYAML('Gruntconfig.yml');

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass:{
            dist:{              
                src: config.scssDir+'style.scss',
                dest: config.cssDir+'style.css'
            }
        },
        concat:{
            dist:{
                src: config.jsSrcDir+'*.js',
                dest: config.jsConcatDir+'app.js'
            }
        },
        jshint:{
            options:{
                "eqeqeq": true
            },
            all:[
                'Gruntfile.js',
                config.jsSrcDir+"*.js"
            ]
        },
        watch:{
            sass:{
                files: config.scssDir+'**/*.scss',
                tasks:['sass']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default',['jshint',
        'sass','concat','watch']);
};
```

and my terminal is always this:

[image]

Comment: Please insert the code from the image as code to your post instead of inserting an image

Comment: what is the output of `console.log( config.scssDir+'**/*.scss' );` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use config variable to avoid this problem. Example:

```
var appConfigVars = {
    sass: 'static/sass'
};

grunt.initConfig({
    appConfig: appConfigVars,
    watch:{
        sass:{
            files: '<%= appConfig.sass %>**/*.scss',
            tasks:['sass']
        }
    }
});
```